# C# DateTime returns default value when set up with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, reflection

I have a static method inside a class that sets up an object at runtime like described here: http://benohead.com/create-anonymous-types-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/

To that newly created object I add properties combined from different objects that are being sent to my method and I set the values in reflection and return the newly created object. All values appear to have values (so far I tested string and int) - but the values are there.

The problem is when I set a DateTime value to a DateTime property - the returned value is 01/01/0001 and not the date I have set.

Here is the code that sets the values in reflection:

```
foreach (string key in values.Keys)
{
    if (sqlParams == null || sqlParams.Contains(key))
    {
        PropertyValue propertyValue = values[key];
        object val = propertyValue.Value;
        if (val == null)
            val = getDefaultValue(propertyValue.PropertyType);
         else if (propertyValue.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) && (DateTime)propertyValue.Value == DateTime.MinValue)
            val = new DateTime(1982, 5, 6);// (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
         myType.GetProperty(key).SetValue(obj, val);
    }
}
```

Why aren't DateTime values being returned correctly?

**Edit**

The complete code:

```
    private static object createDummyObject(Dictionary<string, PropertyValue> values, List<string> sqlParams)
    {
        // Code for creating .NET objects at runtime thanks to:
        // http://benohead.com/create-anonymous-types-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/

        AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Poco.Sql.Assembly"),
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("Poco.Sql.Module");
        TypeBuilder dynamicType = dynamicModule.DefineType("Poco.Sql.DynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);

        foreach(string key in values.Keys)
        {
            if (sqlParams == null || sqlParams.Contains(key))
            {
                PropertyValue propertyValue = values[key];
                addProperty(dynamicType, key, propertyValue.PropertyType);
            }
        }

        Type myType = dynamicType.CreateType();
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

        foreach (string key in values.Keys)
        {
            if (sqlParams == null || sqlParams.Contains(key))
            {
                PropertyValue propertyValue = values[key];
                object val = propertyValue.Value;
                if (val == null)
                    val = getDefaultValue(propertyValue.PropertyType);
                else if (propertyValue.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) && (DateTime)propertyValue.Value == DateTime.MinValue)
                    val = new DateTime(1982, 5, 6);// (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
                myType.GetProperty(key).SetValue(obj, val);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    private static void addProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        const MethodAttributes getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

        FieldBuilder field = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Private);
        PropertyBuilder property = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, new[] { propertyType });

        MethodBuilder getMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_value", getSetAttr, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getIl = getMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_value", getSetAttr, null, new[] { propertyType });
        ILGenerator setIl = setMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        property.SetGetMethod(getMethodBuilder);
        property.SetSetMethod(setMethodBuilder);
    }

    private static object getDefaultValue(Type t)
    {
        if (t == typeof(DateTime))
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        else if (t.IsValueType)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        return null;
    }
```

and the PropertyValue class that is used in the code above:

```
class PropertyValue
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public Type PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It'll be much easier to help you if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that your generated code has a problem with `struct` types and boxing, but since your question doesn't include the pertinent code, that's as far as they can help you.

Comment: I've added the code above

Comment: Great! Can you shorten the code, so that *only* the part required to reproduce the problem remains? Make sure that it still compiles on its own...

Comment: What happens when you step through this code with a debugger? What's the value of `propertyValue.PropertyType`? `propertyValue.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)`? `(DateTime)propertyValue.Value == DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: In debugger everything is fine. But when it's returned to the called than it's not the value I expect. You can see in the code I've put that I set up a specific date and the returned value is still 01/01/0001

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is here?

```
private static object getDefaultValue(Type t)
    {
        if (t == typeof(DateTime))
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        else if (t.IsValueType)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        return null;
    }
```

Dates are stored as a 64-bit signed interger, representing the number of "ticks" (1 tick = 100 nanoseconds) since 12:00 AM 01/01/0001.  When you call `DateTime.MinValue` the output is 01/01/0001.